# SugarCRM SOAP: Logging and Closing "Calls"

Tags: soap, module, call, sugarcrm

I'm trying to log Telephone Calls made via Skype to SugarCRM. I've been able to get as far as hooking onto Skype Events, creating a Call record in Sugar via SOAP (with status as Held or Not Held).

However, any call that I log as "Not Held" remains in an "Open" state (with that x mark beside it) in the Activities section and doesn't float up to the History subpanel.

Now if one clicks on the 'x' mark to close the call, **the status changes to HELD** and only then it moves up to History - which beats the purpose, as I want to **log Unsuccessful Calls too**.

[image]

Is this the default and unavoidable behavior of SugarCRM or is there a way to mark the call as not held and YET close it down? I don't seem to find any field in the sugar database that corresponds to the Close button.

Answer (score 0):

I would add two records to the database close held and closed not held in sugar itself, and analyse the columns that have been updated in the database.

Then just update those columns too as part of your SOAP call.

Love the fact you've got skype logging to sugar... awesome!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll give it a shot and get back to you. I plan to release this tool as open source once it's fully done. Now it's mostly a patchwork of code for quicker implementation. I'll refine and optimize the code and dump it on gitHub and post the link here in case you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the status field with a value of 'Held' or 'Not Held' to have it show up in the History panel. I would check the database to make sure the value is being set correctly, and that you are putting in either 'Held' or 'Not Held' verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll give it a shot and get back to you.